# Network share permissions problems in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, network, permission

After upgrading to Mountain Lion, I have experienced some weird problems with network share permissions.  This network share is a Windows server which I login to like so: `smb://DOMAIN;USERNAME@networkshare.address/folder`

### What I see

[image: Permissions error in TextEdit when saving on network share]

### What I cannot do

- Create a new file and save directly to the share.
- Open an existing file and save my changes.

### What I can do

- Create new folder
- Delete folders and files
- Rename folders and file
- Move folders and files
- Drag and drop from my desktop to the share drive

### Apps that ignore the "problem"

With these programs, I am able to save new file into the share drive and overwrite changes to an existing file.

- Adobe CS6: Photoshop, Illustrator, Dreamweaver, etc
- Microsoft Office: Word, Excel, etc

### Apps that display the permissions error message

With most (all?) Mac apps, the permissions error presents itself in some form or fashion.

- TextEdit, Preview
- Pages, Numbers, Keynote
- Coda 2

Coda 2 is unique in that it will let me "Replace" the file, but clicking "Save" will not work.

[image: Permissions error in Coda 2 when saving on network share]

### What else have I tried?

- I have [Repaired the Home Directory and Permissions and ACLs](http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/15/repair-user-permissions-in-mac-os-x-lion/)
- My IT department has confirmed I have all read/write access to the share drive and has even gone so far as to reapply the permissions to every single folder and file
- I have connected via `cifs` and by using the IP address of the server
- I have joined the domain via the Users and Groups pref pane (all this does is not ask for your network login anymore when connecting to the share)
- I have confirmed with other coworkers this affects them as well (some with Lion, some with Mountain Lion)
- I have checked the "Ask to keep changes when closing documents" option in the General pref pane

As you can see, this is weird.  My IT department suggested I wipe my computer.  <strike>I don't see how that would have any affect and is really a last resort.  I'm hoping someone here can shed light on this before I move forward with that.</strike> Wiping the machine and reinstalling the OS doesn't help.  Word is that it has something to do with ACLs.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but I have a very similar (but somewhat different) issue copying files to a Lion 10.7 share. If I get any responses, they may be helpful to you. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87076/cannot-save-edit-to-mac-share-using-mountain-lion.

Comment: This is a classic POSIX/ACL conflict from my experience. Is it a Mac Server? I'm guessing ACLs haven't been set from server side properly. Wiping your Mac will not fix it. When ACLs are not set on a file share individual files will maintain their own unique permissions based on which group member created the file. I had several issues like this with my first Mac Server I setup and applying ACLs fixed it. If you can provide more info on how the server is configured I may be able to provide more detail, but suffice it to say your Mac is not the problem here.